# $\int _0^{\pi }\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:}\frac{n\cdot \sin \left(nx\right)}{e^n}dx=\frac{2e}{e^2-1}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, trigonometric-series

It is asked to prove:
$\int _0^{\pi }\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:}\frac{n\cdot \sin \left(nx\right)}{e^n}dx=\frac{2e}{e^2-1}$
I have tried to search for convergence and it gave me 0 so i can't solve it. Can you help me?

Comment: The sum-integral interchange can be justified by the dominated convergence theorem, note that $|n\sin (n x)e^{-n}|\leq n e^{-n}$. (which is summable and it integral over $(0,\pi)$ is convergent).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\pi} \sin(nx)=\frac{1}{n}\left(-\cos(nx)\right|_0^{\pi} =\frac{1}{n}\left(1-(-1)^n\right)$$
Hence, 
$$\int_0^{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n\sin(nx)}{e^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1-(-1)^n}{e^n}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^n}\right)-\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{e^n}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)}-\frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac{1}{e}\right)}=\frac{e}{e-1}-\frac{e}{e+1}=\boxed{\dfrac{2e}{e^2-1}}$$

Comment: Thanks! But why can you change the ∫ by the $\sum $?

Comment: I simply moved the integral symbol "inside" the summation but it needs some justification which I cannot help with. Maybe someone else could shed some light about it. Sorry. :)

Comment: @PranavArora. You won by a few seconds ! Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Hehe thanks but looks like OP liked your solution instead. :)

Comment: @PranavArora. I have been surprized too ! +1 for you !

Comment: Sorry! I thought i could accept bouth. Thanks a lot for both of you.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

You could use

$$\int _0^{\pi }\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:}\frac{n\cdot \sin \left(nx\right)}{e^n}dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:}\int _0^{\pi }\:\frac{n\cdot \sin \left(nx\right)}{e^n}dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:}e^{-n} (1-\cos (\pi  n))$$

At this point, I stop since appeared Pranav Arora's very nice answer.